# Markdown and doxygen trying to set image size

Tags: markdown, documentation, doxygen

I am trying to include images in a markdown file that is also an input to doxygen. The images end up looking humongous on the generated html pages so i am trying to make them smaller. I tried 3 things:

Works on markdown, is invisible on doxygen:

```
[<img src="edge_splitting/edge_split_1-1.png" width="800"/>](edge_splitting/edge_split_1-1.png)
```

Works on doxygen, is rendered as plain text on Markdown

`\image html edge_splitting/edge_split_1-1.png width=1200`

Works on both but can't set the size:

`![](edge_splitting/edge_split_1-1.png)`

I have also tried small variations of this, like pure html tags, or appending {width=800px}

But nothing so far works on both systems and also allows to change the size.

My temporary solution is to use smaller images, but I dislike that so I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? I tested it with the current doxygen version (1.8.18) and I did set the `IMAGE_PATH` and as far as I can see this works.